# ubuntu linux problems

Tags: command-line

I have a problem that I feel you will see for the first time. So, I was trying to install php-apc and it broke some pipe. Now, when I start to go by trace to fix everything I need to remove libssl and then put it back. Kindof reinstall.

Here is what it shows me:

```
> root {TEST} # apt-get remove libssl0.9.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libts-0.0-0 libswscale0 libavutil49 libsensors4 lsof libavfilter0 libspeex1 libisccc60 libavcodec52 libdirectfb-1.2-0 liblwres60 libidn11-dev libtheora0
  lm-sensors libpostproc51 geoip-database libraw1394-11 libgsm1 fancontrol libvorbisenc2 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libavformat52 libdc1394-22 libgeoip1
  libperl5.10 tsconf libsysfs2 liboil0.3 libisc60 libvorbis0a libusb-1.0-0 libogg0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-prefork-dev apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apport apt-transport-https bind9 bind9-host bind9utils
  bsd-mailx byobu ca-certificates command-not-found courier-imap courier-imap-ssl courier-pop courier-pop-ssl courier-ssl curl dnsutils dovecot-common dput
  ffmpeg git-core gnupg-curl landscape-common language-selector-common libaprutil1-dev libasound2 libavdevice52 libbind9-60 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libdns64 libisccfg60 libnet-ssleay-perl libpq-dev libpq5 libpython2.6 libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules libsdl1.2debian
  libsdl1.2debian-alsa libsnmp-base libsnmp-dev libsnmp-perl libsnmp15 libssl-dev libssl0.9.8 lsb-release ntpdate openpanel-core openpanel-mod-dnsdomain
  openpanel-mod-domain openpanel-mod-iptables openpanel-mod-mysql openpanel-mod-postfixcourier openpanel-mod-softwareupdate openpanel-mod-spamassassin
  openpanel-mod-ssh openpanel-mod-user openpanel-swupd openpanel-validatepem openssh-client openssh-server openssl postfix pure-ftpd python python-apport
  python-apt python-central python-dbus python-gdbm python-gnupginterface python-gobject python-httplib2 python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient
  python-lazr.uri python-minimal python-newt python-oauth python-openpanel python-openssl python-pam python-pexpect python-pkg-resources
  python-problem-report python-pycurl python-serial python-simplejson python-smartpm python-support python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-wadllib
  python-zope.interface python2.6 python2.6-minimal spamc ssl-cert tcpdump ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ufw unattended-upgrades update-manager-core
  update-notifier-common vim w3m webmin wget wpasupplicant
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  python-minimal python2.6-minimal (due to python-minimal)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 117 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 259MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
?]
```

Any Ideas why and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl0.9.8
```

Or:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libssl0.9.8
```